# Which one of the following is a better Rest URL?

Tags: api, rest, url-design

Just a quick question. Which one of the following makes a better Rest API Url & why so?

1. `GET shop/department/{id}/{action}`
2. `GET shop/department/{action}/{id}`

The action is a verb and it can be:

- <del>`GET shop/department/{id}/download`</del>
- `GET shop/department/{id}`
- `GET shop/department/{id}/receive`

Comment: Plese descibe what `action` is. Please add some examples of URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `action` is an action as in Remote Procedure Call RPC, both are equally bad.

Actions don't belong in URLs but in HTTP verbs.

Comment: A resource is 'any information that can be named'. 'download' seems a poor name for some information ;)

Comment: That's why I asked :) I fear that the order of the path elements will not matter for Resources that are totally un-RESTful.

Comment: @MichaelBrown I agree, 'download' is indeed a very unRestful. I don't know how I came up with it.

Comment: @Obaid Would you please explain what the new path element `receive` means? How does it identify a Resource?

Comment: @Tichodroma, `receive` is not a resource, its more of an action that can be performed on the `department` apart from the usual verbs. (I know receive a department sound weird, but its just an example)

Comment: @Obaid URIs are idenify Resources. Verbs have no place in URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Use actions and corresponding id as parameter

Comment: Parameter of what? What do you mean?

Comment: You mean like this: `GET shop/department/{id}?do=action` ?